# Game engine with javascript scripting

Tags: javascript

Javascript is my favorite language and a few years ago Unity had a options to create JS scripts but its removed for now.
So is here any strong engine like Unity wich still support JS for scripting?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't give technology recommendations.

Comment: @Philipp but i dont need recommendations, i need straight answer.

Comment: Hi Diskyp, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. Our Q&A format is not the best way to get information about what technology supports feature X - this changes quickly over time as new software displaces old, or as features are added/deprecated, so there's a high risk of answers providing outdated information that misleads future users. As a particularly clear example, the accepted answer below claims that no game engines support javascript, when a quick web search for "javascript game engine" or "javascript in [engine name]" turns up *many* options to use the language you want.

Comment: @DMGregory you can say that about most of the answer here cos they depend on some technology. And if you look a bit closely, search for "javascript game engine" give wrong result with engines builded on JS but search for "game engine with javascript scripting" will give you nothing. Anyway i got what i want and dont care about this question anymore. Just post for justice.

Comment: It has not been my experience that answers about game design or solving programming problems go out of date nearly as fast as questions about specific product feature support. A way that worked to solve the problem last year generally still works as a way to solve the problem this year, but hard statements about software options like "there are no engines with JavaScript scripting" become inaccurate readily. I'm afraid if you're finding no engines that meet your needs, you might not be looking in the right places. Try joining us in [chat] if you'd like to discuss some options less formally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a side note Unity [never supported JavaScript](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/) as a language. It was UnityScript which was basically a look-alike language.

There is actually quite few alternative to Unity today and none of them support JS. So if you serious about going into game development you sould not limit yourself to JavaScript.

Comment: Yea, looks like i have no choise, and my hopes die with this unity's JS-like abomination. Thanks.

Comment: "none of them support JS" — I don't think this claim is accurate. Just searching "JavaScript game engine" brings up [whole lists of options](https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines). Even if we limit the search to non-web engines (which wasn't specified in the question), we can find multiple plugins to add JavaScript scripting to Unreal or other PC/console/mobile standalone engines.

Comment: @DMGregory this claim was only applied to Unity alternatives, i.e. expecting "out of the box" product-level support. Yes, for properly designed engines you can script them basically in any language if you like, but that, IMO, is not what author asked about.